# Making a code that counts possible combinations only with loops

Tags: c

I would like some help with a code I'm writing. I need to write a loop that counts the number of combinations for a number I input in the program, and it needs to check how many combinations I can do, with the numbers 10,5,2,1.

For example, if I input 5 there are 4 combinations - (5 | 2 2 1| 2 1 1 1 | 11111).

I have tried to make some loops but I have no idea how to make it work, I was thinking about using a while loop, but I have no idea how to count the combinations, would really much appreciate any help in the matter.

Here is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("enter a number\n");
    int num, i, m = 2, counter = 0, g = 2;
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    for (i = 1; m > 1 ; i++)
    {
        m = num - (5 * i);
        for (i = 1; g > 1; i++)
        {
            counter++;
            g= m - (2 * i);
        }
    }

    printf("The counter is %d\n", counter);
}
```

My general idea is to start from the bottom. For example, if I input 10,
I get `10 -2` and then counter counts 1, then another -2 from 8 (10-2) and it counts again, and when I input a higher number like 5 I would like a loop to remove `10 - 5 = 5`, and then go down to the next loop and count 5 2 2 1, and so on...

I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy that you can use.

Assume the input is N

First you can say: "How many combinations are there if I use 10 exactly **one time**?"

That would be:

```
combinations = calculate_combinations_when_only_using_5_2_1(N-10);
```

Then you can say: "How many combinations are there if I use 10 exactly **two time**?"

That would be:

```
combinations = calculate_combinations_when_only_using_5_2_1(N-20);
```

The next time you use 10 exactly 3 times and so on.

This can be turned into:

```
int calculate_combinations_which_includes_10(int N)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(N >= 10)
    {
        result += calculate_combinations_when_only_using_5_2_1(N-10);
        N = N - 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

With a similar approach you can write a function that return the number of combinations that includes 5 and another function that return the number of combinations that includes 2. Just remember:

```
int calculate_combinations_which_includes_1(int N)
{
    return 1;  // Always exactly 1 combination in this case
}
```

Now you only need `calculate_combinations_when_only_using_5_2_1` and `calculate_combinations_when_only_using_2_1` which I'll leave for you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.!